# How to hide popover in Onsen Ui by clicking on popover?

Tags: popover, onsen-ui

Popover is shown with two list items Admin and Seller. I want to hide popover when user clicks on particular listitem.

```
 My code is :-
 <ons-template id="drpdwnPopUp.html">
 <ons-popover direction="down" id="popover" style="height:50px;width:65px" cancelable>
<ons-list >
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="getPerson(1);">
Admin
</ons-list-item>
 <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" onclick="getPerson(2);">
Seller
</ons-list-item >
</ons-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can just hide it with `popover.hide()`, but it seems there is a bug when you try to use again the same controller with a popover containing a list (the browser gets stuck and the CodePen sample get bugged). That's why you need to create another controller to hide the popover and a service to share the popover between the two controllers (here you can find a [working CodePen](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/pJzPqE)).

```
var app = ons.bootstrap();

app.controller('DropdownController', function($scope, myService) {
  ons.createPopover('popover.html').then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
    myService.setPopover($scope.popover);
  });
});

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, myService) {
  $scope.destroyPopover = function() {
    $scope.popover = myService.getPopover();    
    $scope.popover.hide();
  }
});

app.service("myService", function(){
  var sharedPopover

  var setPopover = function(pop){
    sharedPopover = pop;
  };

  var getPopover = function(){
    return sharedPopover;
  };

  return {
    setPopover: setPopover,
    getPopover: getPopover,
  };
});
```

After, just add the controller in the new `popover.html` template, and the `ng-click="destroyPopover()"` (not `onclick`) directive to the `ons-list-item`. Doing that, the popover will be hidden every time you click the list element.

```
<ons-template id="popover.html" >
  <ons-popover direction="down"style="height:50px;width:65px" cancelable >
    <ons-list ng-controller="MyController">
      <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="getPerson(1);hidePopover()">Admin</ons-list-item>
      <ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="getPerson(2);hidePopover()">Seller</ons-list-item>      
    </ons-list>
  </ons-popover>
</ons-template>
```

**EDIT**

There is another way to hide the popover without using an AngularJS Service.
Since Onsen UI 1.3 release it's possible to pass scope for dialogs and popover, when creating them with `ons.createDialog()`, `ons.createPopover()` and `ons.createAlertDialog()`. ([source](http://codepen.io/andipavllo/pen/ZGzoqg)).

When creating a dialog the following syntax can be used:

```
ons.createDialog('dialog.html', {parentScope: $scope}).then(function(dialog) {
  $scope.dialog = dialog;
});
```

and use

```
<ons-list-item modifier="tappable" ng-click="getPerson(1);popover.hide()">Option 1</ons-list-item>
```